# How do I create a method to generate all possible boolean functions?

Tags: java, boolean

I have used JAVA to create a linked list of 30 nodes. Each node is assigned a random Boolean value when instantiated.

I want each node assigned its own random boolean method/function/rule that takes three Boolean arguments and returns the result:

```
boolean assignedBolMethod(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c) {
     boolean answer  = conduct assigned ruled
     return answer;
}
```

I understand there are 256 such rules to chose from (2^2^3); how could I generate all 256 possible rules without typing them out manually?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Could you explain it a bit more maybe with pseudo code ? Because I can show you how to generate 3 random boolean, if that is the question, but I don't understand your data structure and needs.

Comment: @spi A 'rule' is like a program: Assuming all inputs are entirely constrained by these 3 boolean params, and the only output a 'program' has is 'true', or 'false', then there are only 256 possible programs one could ever write in this universe. OP is asking how one would generate all such programs. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say '0' when we mean false and '1' when we mean true, because that makes this a lot easier to read:

There are 8 different possible inputs (000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, and 111), and for each input, there are 2 possible answers: 0 or 1.

Let's define a 'rule' as follows: We always list all the inputs in that exact order, and then we list the rule's answer to each input in terms of a 1 or a 0. Thus, `00001111` is the rule that says '000 = 0', '001 = 0, 010 = 0, 011 = 0, 100 = 1, ', etcetera - in other words, the rule is: `return a;`, if you were to put it in code.

It is then obvious that there are indeed 256 rules (`2 ^ 8`), and you can represent each rule as **a single byte**, as bytes consist of 8 bits. Every existing byte represents one rule. Thus 'a rule' and 'a byte' are completely interchangeable, thus, this boils down to: How do I generate an arbitrary byte.

And that's easy:

```
Random r = new Random(); // do this once someplace

byte rule = r.nextByte();
```

Alternatively if you want an ordered list of every possible rule:

```
byte[] rules = new byte[256];
for (int i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) rules[i] = (byte) i;
```

But this array is mostly meaningless; it effectively maps '100' to '100' - not very useful. There is no actual need to have a 'list' of all possible rules: Java already ships with it: `byte` - that is a data type that exactly matches. Thus, if you have some code and you want 'rule 100' to be applied, all you need to write is `byte rule = 100;` - no need for a list.

Given a byte that represents a rule, plus those 3 inputs, how do you determine the answer the rule indicates is correct?

Well, first you need to collapse those 3 booleans you have into which one of the 8 bits in your byte represents the answer.

```
int bitPos = (a ? 1 : 0) + (b ? 2 : 0) + (c ? 4 : 0);
```

This gives you the position of the bit (a number between 0 and 7) that determines the answer.

Then, given a bit position and a byte:

```
boolean answer = ((rule >> bitpos) & 1) != 0;
```

Breaking that down:

1. `a >> b` will take the bitstring of a (let's say it's rule `00110111`), and shift it to the right by `b` spots. So if we want the bit at bitpos=2 (so, the third bit), `0b00110111 >> 2` is `0b00001101`. This means the bit we are interested in is now at the very end.
2. `a & b` will take the bitstring of a, and the bitstring of b, and checks for all positions where *both* a and b have a `1`. Then, it returns a new number represented by setting each bit to `1` where both a and b have a one. Therefore, `a & 1` has the effect of zeroing out all bits, except the lowest bit (1 = `00000001` - all bits unset except the lowest bit). It gets rid of all bits, except the bit we care about.
3. `!= 0` then just checks if that bit was set or not.